# Custom event trigger on a jQuery plugin instance

Tags: jquery

I have trouble adding a custom event to a jQuery plugin.

I have made a very simple jQuery plugin from which I trigger an event, but attached handlers don't fire properly: http://jsfiddle.net/FhqNf/2/

```
(function($) {

var my_plugin = function(link, opts) {

    var $this = this, img, o={};

    defaults = {
        color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
    };

    $.extend(this, $.fn, {
        init : function () {
            o = $.extend(defaults, opts);
            link.on('click', $this.changeColor);
        },

        changeColor : function (e) {
            if( link.css('color') == o.color)
                link.css('color', 'blue');
            else 
                link.css('color', o.color);

            $this.triggerChange();
        },

        triggerChange : function () {
            $this.triggerHandler('custom', {test: 'ok', color: o.color} );
        }
    });

    this.init();

};

$.fn.my_plugin = function(opts) {
    return new my_plugin(this, opts);
};
```

Then if I use my plugin and attach a function to my 'custom' event handler, that event doesn't fire:

```
var test1 = $('#test1').my_plugin();
test1.on('custom', function (data) { console.log(data); alert('test1') } );
```

EDIT: a workaround is to attach/trigger the event on the "link" dom object, but I want to trigger events attached to my plugin instance. Isn't that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by properly do you mean what? I see it works.

Comment: no, the 'custom' event handler never get fired, I have updated my question

Answer (score 4):

SOme code modification and its working

in your code your triggering event on different object and attaching handler to different object.

try below

```
 triggerChange : function () {

            link.trigger('custom', {test: 'ok'} );
        }


$.fn.my_plugin = function(opts) {
          new my_plugin(this, opts);
        return this;
    };
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/FhqNf/3/**

Comment: In fact I don't want to trigger the event on the DOM object but rather on the plugin instance, isn't that possible ?

Comment: @Laurent: you could store a reference to the plugin in a data-attribute. So then if the event is fired on your element you can easily access your plugin instance (see https://github.com/acanimal/jQuery-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/jquery-plugin.js).

Answer (score 2):

You need the link to fire the custom event then have the link listen for the custom event.

Your plugin is not returning a jQuery object, so trying to chain the `.on` function to a null return won't do anything.  Try using either the link id or returning the object to keep function chaining working.

I changed it to:

```
link.trigger('mycustomevent');
$("#test1").on('mycustomevent'....);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FhqNf/4/

Comment: In fact I don't want to trigger the event on the DOM object but rather on the plugin instance, isn't that possible ?